# Is There A Canon Reason Why Yoda could Identify Darth Bane

Tags: star-wars, the-clone-wars

In the final season of Star Wars The Clone Wars, at one point, Yoda ventures to the Sith world of Moraband. There he encounters an ancient Sith ghost, whom he is able to identify as Darth Bane. I know this question has already been asked, [(original question)](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/52951/how-can-yoda-identify-darth-bane?rq=1), but the answer was strictly from Legends. Is there a canon reason why Yoda knows who Darth Bane was?

Comment: Sorry, but dissatisfaction with the answers on a question isn't sufficient reason to create a new duplicate. If you don't like the answers, post a bounty.

Comment: The question was asked when Legends was still canon. It doesn't answer my question. It doesn't have a currently canon answer to my question. The answer given is Legends, but was canon when the question was asked.

Comment: Again, a change in canon status (requiring new/better answers) is precisely the purpose of the "Outdated answers" bounty reason