# How does Yoda know that the name of other Sith is Darth Sidious?

Tags: star-wars

At the very end of *Star Wars Episode 1: The Phantom Menace* movie, Mace Windu and Yoda had this conversation:

> Mace Windu: There is no doubt. The mysterious warrior was a Sith.
> Yoda: Always two there are....no more...no less. A master and an
> apprentice.

From this conversation, it's clear that they had no idea about the other Sith (They were surprised to see one Sith). They were just using [their knowledge of Rule of Two](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/13829/when-how-did-yoda-come-to-know-about-rule-of-two) to guess that one other must be alive.

In *Star Wars Episode 3: Revenge of the Sith*, Yoda addressed Palpatine as Darth Sidious. I thought, Yoda discovered Palpatine's Sith name from security hologram (he watched at Jedi Temple).

But, in the last episode of *Star Wars: The Clone Wars - The Lost Missions (Unfinished season 6)*, Yoda called Darth Sidious by his name.

How does Yoda know the name of Darth Sidious? Has Yoda encountered Darth Sidious after the events of TPM?

Comment: If the rule of two is absolute, why be surprised at one Sith. There must always be two about by the Rule of Two.

Comment: @Oldcat They believed that Sith were extinct..

Answer (score 53, accepted):

I think the answer is just that Dooku told Obi-Wan the name in *Attack of the Clones*, and Obi-Wan reported it to the council. From the transcript [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20111217191338/http://www.blueharvest.net/scoops/aotc-script.shtml):

> COUNT DOOKU: The dark side of the Force has clouded their vision, my
>   friend. Hundreds of Senators are now under the influence of a Sith
>   Lord called Darth Sidious.
>
> OBI-WAN: I don't believe you.
>
> COUNT DOOKU: The Viceroy of the Trade Federation was once in league
>   with this Darth Sidious. But he was betrayed ten years ago by the Dark
>   Lord. He came to me for help. He told me everything. The Jedi Council
>   would not believe him. I tried many times to warn them but they
>   wouldn't listen to me. Once they sensed the Dark Lord's presence, it
>   would then be too late. You must join me, Obi-Wan, and together we
>   will destroy the Sith.

And later:

> OBI-WAN: Do you believe what Count Dooku said about Sidious
>   controlling the Senate? It doesn't feel right.
>
> YODA: Becoming unreliable, Dooku has. Joined the dark side. Lies,
>   deceit, creating mistrust are his ways now.
>
> MACE WINDU: Never the less, I feel we should keep a closer eye on the
>   Senate.
>
> YODA: I agree.

Comment: Then, gentlemen, why the f*** haven't you kept a closer eye on the Senate?!

Comment: Because it's called "stalking" and in most civilized systems isn't legal. Also, I don't think Jedi are supposed to be competent in the game of espionage and politics.

Comment: @DarthHunterix Like Ned Stark?

Comment: Actually Ned was supposed to be competent, since he was a nobleman and a ruler of a good chunk of the country. He just wasn't.

Comment: Interesting also in that Dooku even **identifies** Sidious to Obi-Wan and they still don't pick up on it.  Because Palpatine at that point is Chancellor and therefore literally has "hundreds of Senators" under his "influence".