# Were the Jedi taught about the Sith?

Tags: star-wars, jedi, jedi-training

In Episode II, we see this interaction between Obi-Wan and Yoda:

> OBI-WAN  One more thing. Jango mentioned he was recruited by someone
>   named Darth Tyranus. Any idea who that might be?
>
> YODA  With the forename Darth, a Sith he must be.

Did the Jedi not teach about the Sith? It seems odd that Obi-Wan didn't realise that the name Darth was a title pointing to their mortal enemy. I'd prefer a canon answer, and while the Jedi may have believed the Sith extinct, this implies that they already had at least SOME knowledge, from where not knowing about the title Darth would seem to be a peculiar oversight (too much so to be credible).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why did nobody know about the Sith Empire?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/86839/why-did-nobody-know-about-the-sith-empire)

Comment: Also possible duplicate of [Why did the Jedi believe the Sith had been extinct if they knew about the Rule of Two?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/64145/why-did-the-jedi-believe-the-sith-had-been-extinct-if-they-knew-about-the-rule-o?rq=1)

Comment: I would argue no to both on the basis that:
- I'd prefer a canon answer
- Believing something to be extinct reinforces the case that the Jedi should have known what 'Darth' indicated

Comment: Then the proper procedure would be to open a bounty on one or both of those questions and select the "Canonical answer required" option.

Comment: No. This question references canon, that question referred only to KOTOR.

Comment: There are (at least) three questions that would make this a dupe, in my opinion.  http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/86839/why-did-nobody-know-about-the-sith-empire, http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/64145/why-did-the-jedi-believe-the-sith-had-been-extinct-if-they-knew-about-the-rule-o?rq=1, and http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/13829/when-how-did-yoda-come-to-know-about-the-rule-of-two. Probably more.

Comment: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/52952/how-does-yoda-know-that-the-name-of-other-sith-is-darth-sidious?lq=1

Comment: Firehosing questions that reference the Sith isn't helping.

Comment: The point is that this question is a dupe of several others (at least 3-4 by my count so far).  If you don't like the answers to those, please open a bounty on one and ask for canonical answers or authoritative references.  As it sits, this question has been asked before in different ways, however unsatisfying the answers may have been.

Comment: It needs to be mentioned that you're referencing the script. The final theatrical version, however, does not mention the word "Darth" anywhere in the conversations about Tyranus. The conversation you refer to doesn't even really exist anymore. Obi-Wan has to have his message relayed, and cannot interact with the other Jedi masters.

Comment: I don't see how this is a dupe. The Jedi thinking that the Sith were extinct or knowing about the Rule of Two doesn't say much about whether general information about the Sith was part of Jedi training. The "Sith Empire" question is a particularly bad dupe as it is specifically about Legends but this is about canon.

Comment: @Null - Many Jedi seem to know a bit about the Sith;  some answers to the linked questions say all the Jedi Masters did.  That would suggest that either they were taught about it or they individually learned of it on their own by coincidence.  The former seems more likely to me.

Comment: @WadCheber if jedi masters did then also obi wan should know but seemingly in the script he didn't thus possible that only the council itself knew the full extent about sith?

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure the line in the movie that Jango tells Obi-Wan is "I was recruited by a man called Tyranus on one of the moons of Bogden". The Jedi have defeated the Sith, and Obi-Wan had managed to kill Darth Maul in episode 1. The Jedi in the temple knew about the Sith after Qui Gonn speaks to them in episode 1 as well, so it would be safe to assume that the Jedi were not only taught the history of the Sith, but now would know they are still around.

Comment: The Jedi discuss the fact that as far as they are aware, the sith have been extinct for a millenia. Prior to ep 1, they are not aware the sith are still around.

Answer (score 1):

If you read the Darth Bane series you can get a little more background on the last of the Sith that the Jedi were aware of. Even at the time the Jedi thought they had killed the last Sith, they didn't seem to understand them or how they operated. Even thinking that the dark side could simply drive it's user mad.

At the time of the last war between Jedi and Sith, the title 'Darth' was no longer in use, only being secretly resurrected by Darth Bane along with the Rule of Two shortly before he betrayed his fellow Sith and went into hiding with his apprentice Darth Zannah. So for a thousand years the Jedi thought the Sith were extinct along with their teachings. It stands to reason then that what the Jedi did teach about the Sith, which would not have included the Rule of Two, would have been ancient and most likely corrupt.